# quartz making opacity like in paths

Tags: objective-c, quartz-2d

When I set opacity to 0.5,create path and draw it even on self-intersections of this path opacity is the same with other parts of this path. Is there any way to make this effect in other cases? for example when I draw 2 images of same color and opacity in their intersection there is that opacity too.

Comment: This question is a little bit vague; can you please clarify what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the effect you want by changing the blending mode before drawing the images into your context.  You can use `CGContextSetBlendMode` to set the blending mode.  You can find the list of blending modes in the [*CGContext Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGBlendMode).  I suggest trying `kCGBlendModeDarken` or `kCGBlendModeLighten` first.  Try some others if neither of those does what you want.